# ChartJS place y-axis labels between ticks

Tags: javascript, canvas, graph, charts, chart.js

I have the following graph:
[image]

However, i'd like to shift the y axis labels to be the following:[image]

Is it possible to move the y axis labels in between the tick marks with ChartJS, like shown in the example image above?

Functionality is similar to the `options.scales.yAxes[].ticks.position` option, except currently it is defined as `in the x direction for the y axis`, where as I need it in the y direction for the y axis. And better yet, automatically centered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in method in ChartJS for this, at the moment.

You would rather need to create a chart plugin to achieve that.

```
plugins: [{
   beforeDraw: function(chart) {
      var ctx = chart.ctx;
      var yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
      var tickGap = yAxis.getPixelForTick(1) - yAxis.getPixelForTick(0);
      yAxis.options.ticks.fontColor = 'transparent'; // hide original tick
      // loop through ticks array
      Chart.helpers.each(yAxis.ticks, function(tick, index) {
         if (index === yAxis.ticks.length - 1) return;
         var xPos = yAxis.right;
         var yPos = yAxis.getPixelForTick(index);
         var xPadding = 10;
         // draw tick
         ctx.save();
         ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
         ctx.textAlign = 'right';
         ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)';
         ctx.fillText(tick, xPos - xPadding, yPos + tickGap / 2);
         ctx.restore();
      });
   }
}]
```

<sup>**note:** this will hide the first tick (which begins at 0)</sup>

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var barChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'BAR',
         data: [10, 20, 30],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.5)'
      }]
   },
   options: {
      responsive: false,
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }]
      }
   },
   plugins: [{
      beforeDraw: function(chart) {
         var ctx = chart.ctx;
         var yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
         var tickGap = yAxis.getPixelForTick(1) - yAxis.getPixelForTick(0);
         yAxis.options.ticks.fontColor = 'transparent'; // hide original tick
         // loop through ticks array
         Chart.helpers.each(yAxis.ticks, function(tick, index) {
            if (index === yAxis.ticks.length - 1) return;
            var xPos = yAxis.right;
            var yPos = yAxis.getPixelForTick(index);
            var xPadding = 10;
            // draw tick
            ctx.save();
            ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
            ctx.textAlign = 'right';
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)';
            ctx.fillText(tick, xPos - xPadding, yPos + tickGap / 2);
            ctx.restore();
         });
      }
   }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: This worked pretty much out of the box. Awesome. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any way to make the labels not "jump" when the canvas is redrawn? I've detailed the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356432/how-to-prevent-tick-labels-from-jumping-when-drawn-with-chartjs-beforedraw

Answer (score 1):

With current version of Chart.js you can do :

```
y : {
  type: "category",
  labels,
  offset: true,
  grid: { offset: true }
}
```

Comment: This has the side effect of offsetting all data by half of a tick chunk. So the labels and ticks no longer align with the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use: `yAxes: [{gridLines: { offsetGridLines: true }}]` to do this. The label value will be the avg between the thicks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want (as I'm not sure if your Y axis has numbered values), but if your y axis is using numbered values, you can use the `ticks` `callback` and modify the `values` array and add your ticks there, with `value` being the position on the y axis based on the value and `label` as what you want displayed.

```
options: {
  scales: {
    yAxis: {
      ...
      ticks: {
        ...
        callback(value, index, values) {
          values.push({ value: 12.5, label: 'Critical' })
          values.push({ value: 18.5, label: 'Needs Work' })
          values.push({ value: 22.5, label: 'Neutral' })
          ...
        },
      },
```